# Need on OnEdit trigger by using checkbox (A13) to run app script - this is only way to run script on a mobile - assigning to button didn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

`Here's what I have... I want trigger to send email with info, clear the form, clear the checkbox

```
function EmailDues(){
  Dues();
  clear1();
  gotolocation2();
  uncheck();
}
```

the functions follow from here - not sure you need to see those, let me know.

Found this but not sure how to incorporate to run function EmailDues() by clicking checkbox in A13

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation == "A13") {
    if (e.range.getValue == true) {
      // execute something
    } 
    else {
      // execute something else
    }
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet()
  if (sh.getName() == "Your Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 13 && e.value == "TRUE") {
      Dues();
      clear1();
      gotolocation2();
      uncheck();
  }
}
```

If any operations need permission to run they will not run with a simple trigger

Comment: Cooper, got an error - 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')
onEdit @ Code.gs:2

Comment: You cannot run an onEdit function from the script editor or from a menu without also supplying the event object.

Comment: Thanks, I get most of my coding from clipping and pasting - so don't understand "supplying the event object" - no worries.

Comment: the event object is what the e is filled with and it normally comes from the event trigger which is generated when you editor a range in a spreadsheet.

Comment: That worked and solved the problem!